# Connect un kerberized Hive from kerberized cluster using spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive

Recently we moved our spark Jobs to Kerberized cluster. Some of our Spark jobs pull data from another cluster which is not Kerberized yet. When spark job tries to connect to Hive of unKerberized clusters we got Error.

```
20/08/11 19:40:10 WARN metastore: set_ugi() not successful, Likely cause: new client talking to old server. Continuing without it.
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException


20/08/11 19:40:10 WARN RetryingMetaStoreClient: MetaStoreClient lost connection. Attempting to reconnect (1 of 1) after 1s. getAllFunctions
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
```

Full-stack trace  https://pastebin.com/Fvs290Fs

Comment: do you have keytabs for connecting into?

Comment: Yes. for spark submit

Comment: can you share the spark submit command & the actual stack trace here since I could not open the trace usrl.

Comment: kinit -p <user-name> (generating temp token for user)

spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --num-executors 3 --executor-cores 2 --executor-memory 4g  --driver-memory 4g --files some-file.json job_runner.py <args>

Comment: the stack trace is big I cannot add in comment box

Comment: Spark submit command needs to be modified with Kerberos credentials

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219624/discussion-between-iammehrabalam-and-smart-coder).